# If $\sum_{cyc} \frac{(1-a)(1-b)}{ab} =2(\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{a}-3)$ then $a+b+c\ge 1$

Tags: inequality

> If $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{(1-a)(1-b)}{ab} =2(\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{a})-6$$then prove that $a+b+c\ge 1$.$a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^+}$
>   Actually I was motivated by a problem and made this problem. I wasn't able to prove it . Please help me.

Comment: Is this $$\frac{(1-a)(1-b)}{ab}+\frac{(1-b)(1-c)}{bc}+\frac{(1-c)(1-a)}{ac}=2\left(\frac{1}{a}-3+\frac{1}{b}-3+\frac{1}{c}-3\right)$$?

Comment: @above The question is now edited

Answer (score 0):

Let's transform equality:

$\frac{1 - a - b + ab}{ab} + \frac{1 - b - c + bc}{bc} + \frac{1 - c - a + ac}{ac} = \frac{c - ac - bc + abc + a - ab - ac + abc + b - cb - ab + abc}{abc} = \frac{a+b+c - 2ab - 2bc - 2ca}{abc} + 3$

$2(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}) - 6 = 2\frac{ab + bc + ca}{abc}$ - 6

Hence:

$a + b + c = 4(ab + bc + ca) - 9abc = ab(4 - 3c) + bc(4 - 3a) + ca(4 - 3b)$

So if $a, b, c > \frac{3}{4}$, we even have $a + b + c < 0$, which cannot be true.

Therefore $a, b, c < \frac{3}{4}$ and $a + b + c < 9/4$

Comment: I think your answer is not complete.

Comment: @SufaidSaleel, yeah, check it pls

Comment: But it doesn't proves the required inequality. How $a+b+c\ge 1$ and $a+b+c \lt \frac 94$ are same?